# Spring-boot and Thymeleaf not proecssing templates

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have an [app](https://github.com/jetforme/spring-hoa) which is a simplified version of the Spring Bookmark tutorial. In it, Controllers are annotated with `@RestController` and the app only returns JSON.

I've added to mine the ability to return HTML via Thymeleaf templates. My templates are being returned, but they don't seem to be processed by Thymeleaf. I'm using spring-boot, and I've `spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf` to my `build.gradle` [file](https://github.com/JetForMe/spring-hoa/blob/master/build.gradle), but that doesn't seem to be enough.

For example, here's a simple controller for the root:

```
package com.latencyzero.hoa;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;



@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
class
MainController
{
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    ModelAndView
    index()
    {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("index");
        mav.addObject("version", "0.1");
        return mav;
    }
}
```

and `src/main/resources/templates/index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>HOA v${version}</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>HOA v${version}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Results in the following page being rendered:

[image]

The examples I've found suggest this is all I need to do, but it's not working. Do I need some additional configuration annotations somewhere?

Thanks.

Comment: `@RestController` will not work you need a `@Controller` for that.

Comment: From the docs, a `@RestController` is just a `@Controller` with `@ResponseBody`. Nevertheless, it doesn't work with `@Controller`, either.

Comment: Correct. Which means that EVERY methods return value will be marshaller and not passed on to the view resolution mechanism. Add a controller to your question and some configuration...

Comment: @M.Deinum I added some of my code and results. Thanks!

Comment: It does exactly what you told it to do. That is not the way to replace / use EL. You will need to use `th:text` you cannot (afaik) use inline variables with thyme leaf.

Comment: Ah. Well, that's disappointing. Well, thank you very much. Seems to actually be working, with both `@Controller` and `@RestController`. It's a pity it doesn't expand variables anywhere, that's going to be extremely tedious to use. In fact, it's so awful, that I figure I must have something mis-configured.

Comment: Oh, maybe it's not as bad as I feared. Looks like you can use the `${}` expressions inside attribute values. Just a bit more verbose having to put extra `<span>` tags in a lot of places.

Comment: @Rick you can use <th:block th:text="${smth}" /> to avoid extra span element. Or if you use thymeleaf 3 you can use inline text http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#inlining

Comment: Thanks, @destan, that's very helpful. At first it struck me as clunky, but the ability to choose to escape or not is very handy.

Comment: @destan, Hmm. Seems `spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf` doesn't yet support Thymeleaf 3? I found possible help in a [github repo](https://github.com/linux-china/spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf3), but can't quite figure out how to get it wired in.

Comment: @Rick spring-boot `1.4.x` does support Thymeleaf 3 but it pull Thymeleaf 2 by default. You can override default Thymeleaf version by putting this to your `pom.xml`: `<properties>
    <thymeleaf.version>3.0.0.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>
</properties>`

Comment: I was having the exact same problem when I was coding a sample SpringBoot program and M. Deinum's solution to use @Controller worked for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These are the 2 options based on [Thymeleaf Tutorials](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#inlining)

**Inlining Expression**
*- MainController.java*

```
package com.latencyzero.hoa;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;    
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
class MainController
{
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    ModelAndView
    index()
    {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("index");
        mav.addObject("version", "0.1");
        return mav;
    }
}
```

*- index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>HOA v[[${version}]]</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>HOA v[[${version}]]</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**Natural Template**
*- MainController.java*

```
package com.latencyzero.hoa;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;    
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
class MainController
{
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    ModelAndView
    index()
    {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("index");
        mav.addObject("hoa_version", "HOA v0.1");
        return mav;
    }
}
```

*- index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title th:text="${hoa_version}">Default Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 th:text="${hoa_version}">Default Header</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. It actually works, I just didn't realize Thymeleaf doesn't expand expressions anywhere in the code.

Comment: Thank you, It works well and more clear for me with `ModelAndView`

Answer (score 19):

I had faced the similar problem with the @RestController when I replaced it with @Controller it worked as expected.

Comment: `@Controller` is used to mark classes as Spring MVC Controller. `@RestController` is a convenience annotation that does nothing more than adding the `@Controller` and `@ResponseBody` annotations.

Comment: Actually changing `@RestController` to `@Controller` worked for me. This is because `@ResponseBody` binds the method return value to the response body. The return values in `@Controller` annotated classes are interpreted differently.